# Update a table with an aggregate sum from another

Tags: sql-update

I have tables A and B

```
   A                 B
ts  ta             ts   ta
1   0,00           1   10,00
2   0,00           1    5,00
3   0,00           1    6,00
4   0,00           2    3,00
                   2    5,00
                   2   10,00
                   3    5,00
```

And I want to update table A to get this result:

```
   A
ts   ta
1   21,00
2   18,00
3    5,00
```

So far I've tried with this query:

```
update A
set A.ta = C.sta
from (SELECT SUM(B.ta) sta
FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.ts = A.ts
GROUP BY B.ts) C
```

and get this unwanted result:

```
 ts   ta
 1   21,00
 2    5,00
 3   21,00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE A
SET ta = (SELECT sum(ta) FROM B WHERE ts = A.ts)
FROM A
```